# SQL server date time

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am trying to get object which its start date + start time have passed or equal to current datetime and its end date + end time hasn't pass the current datetime. I tried convert current datetime to nvarchar as all my columns are nvarchar. I also tried converting my columns to datetime type but it doesn't work too. Please help

Column:

```
startDate - nvarchar (dd/mm/yyyy)
startTime - nvarchar (hh:mm) 24 hr
endDate - nvarchar(dd/mm/yyyy)
endTime - nvarchar(hh:mm) 24hr
```

i did try to but datetime betwween startDate + startTime AND endDate +startTime, 
but it doesn't seems to work :

```
SELECT * FROM Promo 
WHERE membership = '1' 
AND promoStatus = '1' 
AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GetDate(), 101) + ' ' + 
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, GetDate())) + ':' + 
          RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEPART(mi, GetDate())), 2) BETWEEN
          startDate + ' ' + startTime
AND  endDate + ' ' + endTime
```

i did try other method too :

```
SELECT * FROM Promo
WHERE membership = '1' 
AND promoStatus = '1' 
AND startDate + ' ' + startTime <=  CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GetDate(), 101) + ' ' + 
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, GetDate())) + ':' + 
          RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEPART(mi, GetDate())), 2)
AND  endDate + ' ' + endTime >=  CONVERT(NVARCHAR, GetDate(), 101) + ' ' + 
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEPART(hh, GetDate())) + ':' + 
          RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEPART(mi, GetDate())), 2)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Promo
WHERE
    membership = '1'
    AND promoStatus = '1'
    AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(), 120) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN
        CONVERT(DATETIME, @startDate, 103) + CONVERT(DATETIME, @startTime)
        AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @endDate, 103) + CONVERT(DATETIME, @endTime)
```

---

This line:

```
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(), 120) AS DATETIME)
```

gets the current date time up to its minutes, meaning this will strip off the seconds and milliseconds part of the `GETDATE()`.

And this line:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, @startDate, 103) + CONVERT(DATETIME, @startTime)
```

will combine your date and time variables to form a new `DATETIME` value.

Note that you could have done away with with this if you design the tables using the proper data types.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM Promo
WHERE membership = '1' 
AND promoStatus = '1' 
AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), GetDate(), 120) AS DATETIME) 
    BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, startDate + ' ' + startTime, 120) 
        AND CONVERT(DATETIME, endDate + ' ' + endTime, 120)
```